# WHERE ALL not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find the **details of a employee** if he has credit cards of type A and B.

The table structure is like `{empid, ccno, cctype}` and suppose `empid` 'e1' has all card type.

I tried something like

```
select * from test where cctype = all('A', 'B') and empid = 'e1'
```

but this did not return any rows.

Can you explain why I'm wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ALL` is effectively expanded to the Boolean `and`. Your query is equivalent to:

```
select * 
  from test
 where cctype = 'A'
   and cctype = 'B'
   and empid = 'e1'
```

As `cctype` cannot be both `A` *and* `B` no rows are returned.

Equality checks (`=`) are rarely useful with `ALL`, comparison operators (`>`, `<`, `<>`) are more useful.

If you want to find individuals with both types you'll have to use an aggregate or analytic function over a key:

```
select empid
  from test
 where cctype in ('A', 'B')
 group by empid
having count(distinct cctype) = 2
```

or

```
select *
  from ( select t.*
              , count(distinct cctype) over (partition by empid) as ct
           from test t
          where cctype in ('A', 'B')
                )
 where ct = 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.

Comment: But what if I want to find if e1 holds all the card types available and it is fetched from an inner sub-query? Just asking for a suggestion!

Comment: I was editing as you wrote that. Please look at my answer again.

Comment: Thanks again. It's really helpful.

Comment: Your first option (`... having count(*) = 2`) will have issues if they have 2 `A`s and no `B`s or multiples of both. I think you should use `distinct cctype` within the `count()` there also

Comment: In this case [ANY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_any_all.asp) operator can also be used instead of ALL -> `where cctype = ANY ('A', 'B')`

Comment: @krokodilko - but answers a different question to "... if he has credit cards of type A and B." which is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I've switched it @Damien.

Comment: In conjunction with an appropriate aggregate or analytic function yes it could @krokodilko. But, I just think it's an unnecessary layer of obfuscation - that's what `a in (x, y, z)` does and it's much more obvious what's happening in addition to being more transferable between different SQL dialects